# AWS EC2 t2.micro: sudo apt install and wget connection error

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

AWS t2.micro: sudo apt install and wget connection error.

```
$ wget https://dlcdn.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.67/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.67.tar.gz
--2022-10-04 05:41:44--  https://dlcdn.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.67/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.67.tar.gz
Resolving dlcdn.apache.org (dlcdn.apache.org)... 151.101.2.132, 2a04:4e42::644
Connecting to dlcdn.apache.org (dlcdn.apache.org)|151.101.2.132|:443...


$ sudo apt install net-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  net-tools
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 22 not upgraded.
Need to get 196 kB of archives.
After this operation, 864 kB of additional disk space will be used.
0% [Connecting to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com (3.87.126.146)]
```

Comment: check your VPC network setting (NACL, Route table, NAT, Internet gateway, Public IP ...)

Comment: what to look for in these settings? I did not change anything after launching the instance. thanks.

Comment: Where is the connection error? Your error message does not show any errors?

Comment: followed by many messages : failed to fetch

Comment: just launched a new instance t2.micro, same issue.

Comment: Does the instance have a public IP?

Comment: yes. I can access it using ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing your resolve.conf and add a working Name Server. Google provides a free one, 8.8.8.8.

vi /etc/resolve.conf

nameserver 8.8.8.8

This can help.